# Compare value from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

How to compare between 2 dataframes by 0,1?

df1

```
L_ID    L_Values
1       20-25
2       30-35
3       25
4       45
5       30-45
```

df2
From L_ID in df1, it represents to columns 1,2,3,4,5 in df2

```
Name    1   2   3   4   5
John    25  25  20  30  45
Zara    20  NaN NaN 25  30
Kim     NaN NaN NaN 45  50
```

I would like to compare values in df2, is it range in df1?
yes = 0, no = 1

Expect output in df3

```
Name    1   2   3   4   5
John    0   1   1   1   0
Zara    0   1   1   1   0
Kim     1   1   1   0   1
```

Comment: Hi, what code have you tried? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Also, I can't follow how you get from "John" column 1 = 25 to an expected 0. When do you get an expected 0? When do you get an expected 1? When do you get an expected NaN ?

Comment: "๋John"  for 1 range is 20-25, he got 25 so 25 is in 20-25 then convert to 0

Comment: if NaN = 1,  or if value is not in the range in each column

Comment: @rajah9 do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If "John" for col 1 is 25 and col2 is 25, then why is the expected result for col1=0 and for col2=1?

Comment: "John" for col2 is 25, but in df1: L_ID=2, the value is 30-35. Then df3 col2 for John = 1

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

Just take care for Nan condition in

```
df3.col.iloc[i]==df3.col.iloc[i]
```

if Nan is in sting format, just replace this part of the code with

```
if df3.col.iloc[i]!='Nan'
```

The code is:

```
d={}
for i in range len(df1):
    d[df1.L_ID.iloc[i]]=[]
    temp=df1.L_Values.iloc[i].split('-')
    if len(temp)==2:
        d[df1.L_ID.iloc[i]]=temp
    else:
        d[df1.L_ID.iloc[i]]=[temp[0], temp[0]]

df3=df2.copy()

for i in range(len(df3)):
    for col in df3.columns:
        if df3.col.iloc[i]==df3.col.iloc[i] and d[col][0] <= df3.col.iloc[i] <= d[col][1]:
            df3.col.iloc[i]=0
        else:
            df3.col.iloc[i]=1 
print(df3)
```